# single vulnerability scan with OWASPZAP zapv2

Tags: owasp, zap

I need to make a script that scans a selected issue within a web site using the owaspzap api, but I am having some problems like it does not find a vulnerability that exists when I select this vulnerability, the script with problems is here, it is basically an addition of some functions to the original zap-full-scan.py script, and the call of these functions after instantiating the zapv2 object in the python code, that is, after calling this object the script is the same:

```
SCAN_POLICY = "custom task"
        
def searh_scan(ascan:zapv2.ascan,ids:str or list[str], policy,something_ids = False):
        results = []
        ids = ids if isinstance(ids, list) else [ids]
        for i in ids:
            for scanner in ascan.scanners(policy):
                if scanner['id'] == i:
                    results.append(scanner)
                    if scanner['dependencies']:
                        ids.extend(scanner['dependencies'])
                        continue
                    break    
                
                    
        return results if not something_ids else ",".join([id['id'] for id in results])
    

def active_ascan(ascan:zapv2.ascan,ids, strength='DEFAULT-DEFAULT'):
    ascan.remove_scan_policy(SCAN_POLICY)
    ascan.add_scan_policy(SCAN_POLICY)
   
    if not re.match(f"^(MEDIUM|HIGH|DEFAULT|LOW)\-(MEDIUM|HIGH|DEFAULT|LOW|INSANE)$", strength):
        strength +="-DEFAULT"
    
    id_scans = searh_scan(ascan, ids, SCAN_POLICY, something_ids = True)
    if not id_scans: 
        return False
    for idp in range(0,5):
        ascan.set_policy_alert_threshold(idp,strength[:strength.find('-')])
        ascan.set_policy_attack_strength(idp, strength[strength.find('-')+1:])
    
    
    ascan.disable_all_scanners(SCAN_POLICY)
    result = ascan.enable_scanners(ids=id_scans, scanpolicyname=SCAN_POLICY) == 'OK'
    if result:
        if strength != 'DEFAULT-DEFAULT':
            ascan.set_scanner_attack_strength(id_scans,strength[:strength.find("-")], SCAN_POLICY)
            ascan.set_scanner_alert_threshold(id_scans, strength[strength.find("-")+1:], SCAN_POLICY)
        
        
            
    return result


def add_custom_task(zap:zapv2, tasks:dict):
    
    if not isinstance(tasks,dict):
        raise TypeError("expected a dictionary in the tasks parameter")
    
    for value in tasks.items():
        if not re.match(r"^((MEDIUM|HIGH|DEFAULT|LOW)\-(MEDIUM|HIGH|DEFAULT|LOW)|(MEDIUM|HIGH|DEFAULT|LOW))$", value[1]):
            raise ValueError('expected "MEDIUM" or "HIGH" or "LOW" or "DEFAULT" with threshold and strengh')
    
    zap.pscan.disable_all_scanners()
    
    for id in tasks:
        if not active_ascan(zap.ascan, id, tasks[id]):
            if zap.pscan.enable_scanners(ids=[id]) != 'OK':
                raise vulnerability_not_found(f"Api owaspzap don't find vulnerability id {id}")
            zap.pscan.set_scanner_alert_threshold(id,tasks[id])
```

I took some examples from the git hub page, but apparently they are the same, I can't see where the problem is. Note: The problem only occurs for some vulnerabilities such as XSS, XSLT Injection

new note: I ended up following an example from the creators git of how to do a custom scan for just one vulnerability, and instead of adding it to the code, I made a mini version for the active scans, but it gives the same problem, here's the script:

```
    def searh_scan(ascan:zapv2.ascan,ids:str or list[str], policy,something_ids = False):
        results = []
        ids = ids if isinstance(ids, list) else [ids]
        for i in ids:
            for scanner in ascan.scanners(policy):
                if scanner['id'] == i:
                    results.append(scanner)
                    if scanner['dependencies']:
                        ids.extend(scanner['dependencies'])
                        continue
                    break    
                
                    
        return results if not something_ids else ",".join([id['id'] for id in results])
    

def active_ascan(ascan:zapv2.ascan,ids, strength='DEFAULT-DEFAULT'):
    ascan.remove_scan_policy(SCAN_POLICY)
    ascan.add_scan_policy(SCAN_POLICY)
   
    if not re.match(f"^(MEDIUM|HIGH|DEFAULT|LOW)\-(MEDIUM|HIGH|DEFAULT|LOW|INSANE)$", strength):
        strength +="-DEFAULT"
    
    id_scans = searh_scan(ascan, ids, SCAN_POLICY, something_ids = True)
    if not id_scans: 
        return False
    for idp in range(0,5):
        ascan.set_policy_alert_threshold(idp,strength[:strength.find('-')])
        ascan.set_policy_attack_strength(idp, strength[strength.find('-')+1:])
    
    
    ascan.disable_all_scanners(SCAN_POLICY)
    result = ascan.enable_scanners(ids=id_scans, scanpolicyname=SCAN_POLICY) == 'OK'
    if result:
        if strength != 'DEFAULT-DEFAULT':
            ascan.set_scanner_attack_strength(id_scans,strength[:strength.find("-")], SCAN_POLICY)
            ascan.set_scanner_alert_threshold(id_scans, strength[strength.find("-")+1:], SCAN_POLICY)
        
        
            
    return result


def add_custom_task(zap:zapv2, tasks:dict, url:str):
    
    if not isinstance(tasks,dict):
        raise TypeError("expected a dictionary in the tasks parameter")
    
    for value in tasks.items():
        if not re.match(r"^((MEDIUM|HIGH|DEFAULT|LOW)\-(MEDIUM|HIGH|DEFAULT|LOW)|(MEDIUM|HIGH|DEFAULT|LOW))$", value[1]):
            raise ValueError('expected "MEDIUM" or "HIGH" or "LOW" or "DEFAULT" with threshold and strengh')
    
    zap.pscan.disable_all_scanners()
    
    for id in tasks:
        if not active_ascan(zap.ascan, id, tasks[id]):
            if zap.pscan.enable_scanners(ids=id) != 'OK':
                raise vulnerability_not_found(f"Api owaspzap don't find vulnerability id {id}")
            zap.pscan.set_scanner_alert_threshold(id,tasks[id])
    
    scanId = zap.spider.scan(url= url, maxchildren=None, recurse=True, 
                             contextname=None, subtreeonly=None)
    time.sleep(2)
    while int(zap.spider.status(scanId)) < 100:
        logging.info(f"Spider progress in {zap.spider.status(scanId)}%")
        time.sleep(2)
    
    zap.ajaxSpider.scan(url=url, inscope=None)
    while zap.ajaxSpider.status != 'stopped':
        time.sleep(10)
    scanId = zap.ascan.scan(url=url, recurse=True, inscopeonly=None, scanpolicyname=SCAN_POLICY, method=None, postdata=True)
    while int(zap.ascan.status(scanId)) < 100:
        time.sleep(5)
    return zap.core.alerts(baseurl=url, start= 0,count= 5000)
```